# How can npm module 'mathbox' be imported and used in an Angular 4 application?

Tags: angular, three.js

I am developing an Angular 4 application which imports and uses the npm module 'three' for rendering 3D scenes.

I have not been able to import and use the npm module 'mathbox'. I would like to use it's api for creating 3D axis, label, ticks, grids etdc.

Can you point me to an Angular 4 example which imports and uses mathbox?
Any help is appreciated,

Thanks 
Dennis